# 20 cricketers and a way to choose a team of 11

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are 20 cricketers which consists of 9 batsmen,8 bowlers and 3 wickets keepers.

A team of 11 must have at least 5 batsman,four bowlers and 1 wicket keeper. 
How many different teams can be selected?

OK,  I got the answer by doing: $${9\choose6}\cdot{8\choose 4}\cdot{3\choose 1} + {9\choose5}\cdot{8\choose5}\cdot{3\choose1} + {9\choose5}\cdot{8\choose5}\cdot{3\choose2}= 65268$$
My question is whether you could get the same answer using ${9\choose5}\cdot{8\choose4}\cdot{3\choose1}\cdot{10 \choose1}$ which obviously doesnt give the answer above. I realise that ${9\choose5}\cdot{8\choose4}\cdot{3\choose1}\cdot{10 \choose1}$ will give rise to double counting but is there to calculate it using the 2nd approach?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second approach is double counting.  The $3C1$ chooses a wicket keeper.  If the odd player selected is also a wicket keeper you could get the same roster by picking the second wicket keeper as the $3C1$ and the first as the odd player.  Your second approach counts these separately, as well as all the other options for the odd player.  You have counted the rosters with six batsmen six times each.

Comment: Is there a way to get the the same answer using the 2nd approach? How do i calculate the common combinations?

Comment: Not an easy one as the overcount depends on which type of player is the odd one.

Comment: Ok a waste of time then. Thanks for replying